# How to resolve SAML response error invalid name id policy

Tags: saml, adfs, claims-based-identity, nextcloud

I'm setting up sso trough SAML using ADFS as identity provider and Nextcloud as service provider and I'm getting following errors: http://prntscr.com/nvba8f on nextcloud and http://prntscr.com/nvbb3w and http://prntscr.com/nvbbfp on adfs. This is my adfs claim issuer configuration 1) http://prntscr.com/nvbc8n
2) added rule on Claimes Provider Trusts http://prntscr.com/nvd5hl
Any and every answer is very appreciated

```
<samlp:Response ID="_dba1e442-d44b-42da-a10b-b16d4daad325"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2019-05-30T08:58:04.396Z"
                Destination="https://192.168.1.136/index.php/apps/user_saml/saml/acs"
                Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_5375bf1eef470709c2c4f2808e9d04f8c396518b"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://WindowsServer19.server.net/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <ds:Reference URI="#_dba1e442-d44b-42da-a10b-b16d4daad325">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <ds:DigestValue>eh+azCJ1VN90c8Oqm5m+ilgUndA=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
2MjM+rjCAyqUKOedfJJpUFxJ/0YHV3SuaWl1t/tooXIeVaSoei38DzrbVW7aMBKh8xGD/4bJa2Wkaljb2UvY1RRWUbeFP7GrOjOwYhXzGnOyFKW3hCvy9DRpe+aWwk2iMNmjCJbJY28i5E5v2UjhsjNXZB08/LiapYjoEvA95xp3q0DKf1EPJHFeUnVw1wwHlvrdhgWOUsV/vuf1kAKM2IiRbzOkxH//ChSH0BplrUqN64ed3Qs97XGzuPTOKuDpUxXz8B28lacC6y9YoQzwNnIiCuAPN6Tw4Xk8kJDn/J93TLJXyUNFe9NwJGr3VYTegG16G7lcLxyERFWdtUMrOA==
</ds:SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>
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
</ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester">
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy" /></samlp:StatusCode>
  </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NameID needs to be in the format of "X509 Subject Name".

So take the attribute that you are using for NameID and do a Transform rule with an output of NameID and format of "X509 Subject Name".

Your current format is "email".

Comment: Thanks for replay i fixed it by setting "Show Service Provider settings…">>"Name ID format" to "Unspecified" at Service provider data (nextcloud).